# Fit multidimensional feature into design matrix

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, feature-engineering

I'm having trouble understanding how I can have a multidimensional feature in my design matrix. I understand the concepts of PCA, but I'd rather avoid it. I have the feeling that I'm missing out on some knowledge here, since this seems to have a trivial solution that I wasn't able to find or figure out.

$X$ is my sample x feature matrix, where the class label is also added. The features are $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$.

$$
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
       \text{class} & f_1 & f_2\\
       1 & 0 & 3           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0           & 6 \\[0.3em]
       2           & 4 & 3  \\
       2 & \dots & \dots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
f_3 = \begin{bmatrix}       
       a & x      \\[0.3em]
       b & y      \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

I don't know how to fit $f_3$ in there.

I want to use this kind of structure for classification with an SVM, where $f_3$ would be a SIFT/SURF/HOG/or-something-else-that-I-don't-know-yet descriptor.
I'm using libsvm or the SVM in matlab; I haven't decided yet.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd definitely recommend LIBSVM over the Matlab SVM. I remember some weird numerical issues with the Matlab one, and LIBSVM is very standard (the implementation paper has >20,000 citations...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can just put each component of $f_3$ in there as its own feature:

\begin{bmatrix}
       \text{class} & f_1 & f_2 & f_{3,a} & f_{3,x} & f_{3,b} & f_{3,y}\\
       1 & 0 & 3 & .1 & 2 & 8 & 4  \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0 & 6 & 12 & 4 & 3 & 6  \\[0.3em]
       2 & 4 & 3 & 4  & 5 & 3 & .18  \\
\end{bmatrix}

or whatever.

If you're doing SIFT/SURF/HOG features, those are high-dimensional (SIFT being 128, or 384 if you do color). For linear classifiers, that's fine. But if you're doing an RBF kernel or something like that, bear in mind that the SIFT feature will then be considered 128 times "as much" in computing distances, which may not be what you want; you might have to [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) and then possibly scale different feature dimensions to have different importances.